# What should I add as api-address when within a multi-container docker-compose setup?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple 2 container docker-compose setup. A frontend (Angular) and a backend (nestjs/express).

Here's my docker-compose (development)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:10-alpine'
    container_name: 'postgresnew'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=4321
      - POSTGRES_DB=bleh
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  frontend:
    build: ./frontendapp
    ports:
      - 4001:4200
    volumes: 
      - ./frontendapp:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
  backend: 
    build: ./backendapp
    ports: 
      - 4000:8080
    volumes:
      - ./backendapp:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

Now, having exposed the correct ports, my frontend is able to access the backend pretty easily using a localhost:4000 address, as seen in my frontend environmnent

```
const x = 'http://localhost:4000';

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_USERSERVICE: x + "/api/user",
  API_PROJECTSERVICE: x + "/api/project",
  API_TASKSERVICE: x + "/api/task",
  API_PGROUPSERVICE: x + "/api/pgroup",
  API_KPISERVICE: x + "/api/kpi",
  API_FUNDRAISINGSERVICE: x + "/api/fundraising"

};
```

But I would like for it to connect using docker's internal bridge network; instead of `localhost:4000`, and I'm not sure what to use as its address... I tried `const x = 'http://twrapp_backend_1'` which is it's name, but I got a CORS error, plus, it seems like it was trying to access a website called by that name... I tried `const x = 'twrapp_backend_1'` as well... I googled this for a week, not sure if I'm making a mistake on the docker end of things, or on the angular end of things. Help!

Comment: Also tried ```x='http://twrapp_backend_1:8080'```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot request your backend service via docker's internal bridge network. because your request to backend service is invoked by the browser who is not in the docker's internal bridge network.
[image]
Only containers in `Docker containers` rectangle is supposed to calling each other withing container's name.

Comment: I guess I needed to hear this. So, the only option would be to connect to the external link, even in Production?

Comment: In production, your backend service is deployed in the server remotely. commonly we request backend service via domain and pathname, like `api.example.com/user/login`. To do that, you maybe need `dns resolve` and `reverse proxy`(for multi services).